# Kusto command for generating create table & function script

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Kusto explorer does allow scripting out functions and tables using the UI option "make command script". Is there any way we can use some sort of Kusto command to generate exactly the same output?  Basically looking for command counterpart for clicking "make command script".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing Yoni's answer, this should give you an executable command

```
.show table MyTable cslschema | project strcat(".create table ",TableName," (", Schema , ")")
```

- `project` lets you select what to output (same as `SELECT` in sql)
- `strcat` lets you concat string

Comment: note that if the table name requires it, you may need to normalize it (as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#identifier-naming-rules)

Comment: yes closest, this doesn't take folder information into consideration though or docstring etc

Answer (score 3):

`.show table T cslschema` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/tables#show-table-schema)) should bring you close to that